# Circle - fill the body

Tags: java, android, box2d, libgdx, geometry

I have a problem with scalling. My circles are not filled as I want.

[image]

Problem is with diffrent resolutions of screens. Image My base window size is 900x600. At the picture is 1000x600. i dont want to keep aspect ratio just stretching this circle to fill the body. Second problem is that is not a circle it is arc. I have to do multi colored circles with arc.

its a code for picture @up:

```
cam = new OrthographicCamera(9, 6);
cam.position.set(9f/2, 6f/2, 0);
cam.update();
```

9x6 for easier calculations in box2d. i tried to do sth with shapeRenderer setProjectionMatrix or setTransform Matrix but probably i don't know how to do it right.
Any ideas?

```
    x = body.getPosition().x;
    y = body.getPosition().y;

    Vector3 v = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
    cam.project(v);

    Vector3 rad = new Vector3(radius * 0.99f, (float) Math.toDegrees(body.getAngle()), 0);
    cam.project(rad);

    float angle = 360 / colorList.size();

    float start = 0;
    for(Color c : colorList)
    {
        shapeRenderer.setColor(c);
        //shapeRenderer.circle(v.x, v.y, rad.x);
        //shapeRenderer.
        shapeRenderer.arc(v.x, v.y, rad.x, (float) (start+Math.toDegrees(body.getAngle())), angle,30);
        start += angle;
    }
```

Comment: "At the picture is 1000x600" Do you mean your Screen is 1000x600? Show how you render this stuff, not just the camera...